# Image Distortion in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a weird issue that causes an Image to get distorted if I re-size the window to a particular size. I'm assuming the image is being positioned inside the scrollviewer to a sub pixel position , but I'm not really sure how to fix this.

I'm using a Scaletransform, but the current issue is happening if the scale is set to 1.

If you Look at the Text in the screenshot below you'll see the text is slightly distorted , If i re-size the window by a single pixel , the distortion goes away as seen in the alternate screenshot.

**Pixel Distortion**

[image: Pixel Distortion]

**No Distortion**

[image: No Distortion]

**XAML Code**:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
          Background="#282828"
          Focusable="False"
          Grid.Column="2"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid Name="grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"      SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>


        <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               Stretch="Uniform" />

    </Grid>
</Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch: Have you tried to apply `UseLayoutRounding`?